# How do I install KDE Plasma 4 instead of 5? Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, kde, kde4

The deal is that I don't like KDE 5 but if I install KDE it installs 5.3.1... Is there a way to install KDE 4 or do I have to deal with it?